# image in div not centering (HTML/CSS) using Margin: 0 auto;

Tags: html, css, margin

Before you reply: I've looked and tried the other stack overflow questions, none of them have solved my problem and they all have similar answers:

So here's the basic code for the image:

```
    <div class="logo-con">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150/" class="logo1"/>
    </div>
```

Very basic indeed. Here's the CSS which doesn't center the image, all it does is move the image a little bit towards the right (about 30:70)

SORRY I ACCIDENTLY PRESSED THE ENTER BUTTON AND IT PRE-POSTED, HERE'S THE CSS:

```
.logo1 {
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 4px solid orange;
    display: block !important;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo-con {
    width: 100%;
    display: block !important;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

WHAT HAPPENS WHEN I DO THIS
http://i.gyazo.com/6a547a51c833aba47e8e8697eef1de46.png

## EXTRA INFORMATION - WHEN THE BROWSER SIZE IS BELOW 880PX IT IS IN THE CENTER, WHEN IT GOES ABOVE THAT - IT ISNT.

TO TOP THIS OFF, MY WHOLE PAGE SEEMS TO BE BREAKING. WHEN I REFRESH WHILST A MEDIA QUERY IS ACTIVE, IT BREAKS THE STYLES WHEN YOU TRY TO RESIZE, YOU NEED TO REFRESH TO MAKE IT LOOK NORMAL AGAIN, ARE THESE LINKED?

================================================================================

Because it seems to work fine on a fiddle, here's my page code, am i missing something?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

        <!-- Stylesheets -->
        <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    </head>

    <body>

    <!-- <img src="http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/tom_clancys_the_division_2015_game-wide.jpg" alt="..." class="bg-img"/> -->

    <div class="main">
        <span class="g-site-title">example</span>
        <ul>
            <a href="#"><li class="active">example</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>example</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>example</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>example</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>example</li></a>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="logo-con">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150/" class="logo1"/>
    </div>




    <!-- AJAX/jQuery -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>


        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Code Here
        });


    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body, html, .main {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* Header Open */

.main{
    background-color: #6E696B;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.g-site-title {
    font-family: 'Oxygen','Arial';
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    margin-left: 45px;
}

ul {
    margin-right: 50px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-right: 35px;
    font-family: 'Oxygen','Arial';
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

li.active {
    background-color
}

a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li:hover {
    background-color: orange;
}

.logo1 {
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 4px solid orange;
    display: block !important;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo-con {
    width: 100%;
    display: block !important;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: please add the css of logo1 class

Comment: the CSS didnt make it

Comment: Seem like it did center for me, have a look at the jsfiddle and let me know if you're not seeing the same? http://jsfiddle.net/tv9erov7/

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine :)

Comment: The problem is, it doesn't work fine. Everything on my page seems to be breaking, i have no idea why.

Comment: It's because of your menu floating. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You needed a `overflow:hidden` for your `.main` class. I've updated my JSFiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/tv9erov7/1/

Comment: Fixed, any chance you could tell me why it was breaking because of that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this CSS:

```
display:block;
```

This needs to be applied to the image.

Comment: @ConorReid I did read the question. I posted this BEFORE you added your CSS... good luck

Answer (score 0):

There is no CSS but if you're having an issue with `margin: auto 0` it's most likely because `img` tags are `inline` by default and will ignore that rule. Set:

```
.logo1{
  display: block;
}
```

**UPDATE AFTER CSS WAS POSTED**

This looks fine:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dkv40891/)

**NEW UPDATE**

It's a float issue in your header. You need to clear your floats with a clearfix or `overflow:hidden` on the parent which is `.main`

[NEW FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dkv40891/1/)

Comment: I did, you didnt have the CSS posted when I answered. I took a guess. Look at my fiddle. It's centered just fine